# React navigation goBack() and set parent state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a page. Screen as below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
export default function ViewA() {
     const [val, setVal] = useState('')
     return (
          <View>
               <Text>{val}</Text>
               <Button title="Next" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate(?)} />
          </View>
     );
}
```

and another page. Screen as below :

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";
export default function ViewB() {
     return <Button title="back" onPress={()=>navigation.goBack(?) } />;
}
```

I have two Screen viewA and viewB. in viewA a have a button. when the button press navigate to viewB and pass the `setVal()` function as param. then in Screen viewB when back button tap `setVal()` call with new value and `navigation.goBack()` call to come back to viewA

Comment: Hi, could you help further edit the post and add a clear question? As it's hard for me to understand where your problem is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a callback function as a param from screen A to B and when button press in screen B pass your new value you like to set in the sceen A.

**Complete Code:**

**Screen A**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, Button } from "react-native";

const ViewA = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(null);

  const callBack = (value) => {
    setVal(value);
  };

  const onNextPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Second Screen", { callBack: callBack });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{val}</Text>
      <Button title="Next" onPress={onNextPress} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ViewA;
```

**Screen B**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Button } from "react-native";

const ViewB = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const onBackPress = () => {
    const { callBack } = route.params;
    callBack(5); // Your new value to set
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="back" onPress={onBackPress} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ViewB;
```

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: tanks' a lot MR Hamas Hassan for your answer . I appreciate you for your answer . you helped me a lot with this code . good luck in your life

Comment: hello. another warning . in screen B I have two values to set: callBack(Id, OrganName); when I  enter the screen a warning appears: non-serializable values were found in the navigation state. how can I solve it

Comment: Your welcome brother. You can sent values as an object {id, OrganName} and get them back in callback function by value.id and value.OrganName. or you can send two parameter and set callback to accept two params.

Comment: tanks a lot brother for your answer and guide.